# Some issue with simulating mini2440 on Qemu

Tags: arm, virtualization, simulation, virtual-machine, qemu

I have compiled qemu for mini2440, I got the source code from here.
http://gnufiish.org/trac/wiki/Qemu

I am able to run the arm image provided on the wiki site of Qemu, no issues here.
I compiled u-boot for versatilepb and ran it.. still no issues.

I then ran this simple command

```
qemu-system-arm -M mini2440   -m 128M
```

and I am getting this error message.

```
S3C: CLK=240 HCLK=240 PCLK=240 UCLK=57
QEMU: ee24c08_init
DM9000: INIT QEMU MAC : 52:54:00:12:34:56
QEMU mini2440_reset: loaded default u-boot from NAND
QEMU mini2440_reset: loaded override u-boot (size 0)
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x00001000

R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=33f80004 R15=00001000
PSR=400001db -Z-- A und32
Aborted
```

**qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x00001000**

Now coming to this error , what I read was that qemu was not able to find the OS on default location of 0x00001000 ...
good enough.. So i tried creating a kernel zImage from source.. still same error
I tried creating u-boot for mini2440 ... still same error..

How do I resolve this.. I am getting this error particularly for mini2440

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you using this command to boot your kernel with qemu-system-arm?

```
qemu-system-arm -M mini2440 -m 128M -kernel <kernel_image>
```

And, what is the host architecture and which crosstool are you using to compile the kernel image?

Answer (score 1):

Your uboot image size is 0, so while booting the uboot.bin is not getting loaded. Ensure that the uboot image is in the same folder from which you are executing your start command.